# Acumatica PXDimension Selector Causing Endpoint to Fail. - Rest Api -

Tags: acumatica, endpoint

I am trying to upload a file via the standard endpoint /entity/default/18.200.001/Project/projectname/files/filename . The project DAC extension ContractCD itself has a PXRestrictor where [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where>>), "Projects are not of current Branch")] .

The restrictor is causing the endpoint to fail if the project we are uploading does not have the same default branch from the User Profile Screen SM203010.  I want to add a condition to the PXRestrictor similar to [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where,Or>>) or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Acumatica 19r2 you can actually specify a "Current" branch for a REST API request.
Try adding a special header `PX-CbApiBranch` with branch name (e.g. "Products Retail") as a value.

Comment: Thanks that is what I needed